# dynamic voice xml

Tags: dynamic, readfile, voicexml

I want to read a dynamic number of products from a textfile.
Then i want to use all these products in my voicexml file.

(use: in a menu for example)

How can I do this?

Is it good to create for each product a form?
Or is it better to put all products in an external grammar file? an use those in the .vxml file?

are there any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few choices, but all involve adding an application server to the equation.

1. Generate your VoiceXML page with JSP or ASP and use the implementation language to read the file.
2. Implement as a servlet (more or less same as #1)
3. Use the VoiceXML [Data element](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/#sec-data) to request the list from an application server as XML.  The VoiceXML document can then use Javascript to piece through the data or directly play using the  [foreach element](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/#sec-foreach) to enumerate over the values.

Comment: I use an MS Speech Server, there is a "Microsoft Office Communication Server 2007 - Speech Server" is this the application server that I need?

Comment: @Tyzak: Sorry.  I haven't worked with that communications suite enough to outline all of the components in the stack.  And, I believe the name has changed as it's now part of Lync.  This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448066.aspx shows a logical overview of the architecture and clues to the components, but it doesn't sufficiently explain the necessary product components.